# Communication between three kinect 2 setup in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, kinect

I want to capture kinect streams from three different devices. I have create a windows form application which in fact captures the stream from one kinect and stores it to the hard disk. I want to do the same for three kinects v2. Thus I have set up a system with three kinects and three PCs. How is it possible those PC to communicate with each other? I know that I have to create a server - client architecture and I have to run my app from the server and the clients to send the data to the hard disk. How can I perform that communication between the devices? Basically I want to things

- To open, record and stop the kinect stream in the same time for the three devices.
- Upload everything in the server (**this has already be done! I have created a filezilla server and I send the data using a simple C# scirpt.**)
- **EDIT:** My app is a windows form application I want when I am pressing the record button from that app to simultaneously record from both three kinects.

Comment: Do you want to stream all the Kinect data to one computer to be save in real time?

Comment: I want two things the first one is to start recording in the same time , and stop recording in the same time. This is my important issue. The second one is to record everything to the server. This task I thing is the easiest one since I can send it to the server using a Filezilla setup.

Comment: Starting and stopping recording isn't that hard. If you have a server and some clients the server can send a command to tell the clients when to start recording. Do you need all the data returned to the same place at the same time, or will you use it after recording? If you wait until you finish recording you won't have to transfer kinect data over a network (which might slow if it involves video)

Comment: The important thing is the stop and start of the recording (simulataneously). Data could be send it afterwards.  However I am not familiar on how to perform the communication of the devices. I have my project in the server. I have to create a service which will activates the other pcs? Thus I have to activate the same executable from the three pcs in the same time and stop ip in the same time.

Comment: A really simple 'hack' could be to use the `DateTime` method in .NET to manually set a start time and stop time (down to the millisecond). You could then expand it to use a TCP IP server to communicate that start and stop time from a central location. I would avoid sending large amounts of data over a network unless you really need to, so if you can retrieve the data after you finish that would be best.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on how to setup the TCP IP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a WCF service on the server.

If you don't know WCF, you can start by looking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx

The service can then be configured to do binary over TCP. In your case, you don't want to use SOAP over HTTP. It would be very slow to transfert image data that way.

Comment: Ok step by step. In the server I wll have my c# project. which now just opens a kinect stream. I dont know it, however I wll create a WCF service. What in fact that service it will perform?

Answer (score 2):

There are various examples of TCP server client models in C# which can be used to communicate start/stop commands. You just need to come up with a simple set of rules that tell the clients what to do (i.e. start recording, stop recording, send acknowledgements etc)

If you have specific problems with the server client model then take a look around SO, there are plenty of good examples.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5733/A-TCP-IP-Server-written-in-C

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx